# replace and multiply a value in GREL or Python

Tags: python, string, openrefine, grel

I am trying to do the following operation in either GREL or Python where I replace a string if it contains "$" and replace it with a value * 0.77 , if the string does not contain, then the value remains same.
I did the following `if(value.contains("$"),value.replace("$",""), value)`
so i was able to remove $. How do I multiply those values which had a dollar with 0.77?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
if(value.contains("$"),
toNumber(value.replace("$",""))*0.77,value)
```